# Do you have to specify the zero polynomial exception when talking about roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

E.g.  I want to prove that for a primitive $nth$ root of unity there exists no integer polynomial of degree less than $n$ such that the primitive root is a root of the polynomial.  But everything is a root of the zero polynomial, so how do you handle that?  Is it conventional to just ignore that?

For example there exists no nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $\lt k$ such that $e^{i 2\pi /k}$ is a root.

Should I leave out the nonzero part?

Comment: This is not true. For example, $i \in \mathbb{C}$ is a primitive $4$th root of unity but is a root of $X^2 + 1$

Comment: But yes you would exclude the zero polynomial

Comment: Crap, not true eh?  Darn

Comment: @Enjoys Math You can show that there is no polynomial of degree less than $\varphi(n)$..

Comment: One way to avoid worrying about the zero-polynomial is by agreeing it does not have a degree (and it really doesn't).